# dronekit-android API addMavlinkObserver causes system crash

Tags: android, dronekit, dronekit-android

I am using [dronekit-android](https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-android) packages that can successfully connect to PX4 board. However, I try to receive the mavlink message in a while 1 thread, the receive API addMavlinkObserver causes the system crash.

After the drone is connected, I simply call this function upon pressing a button and it crashes.

```
this.drone.addMavlinkObserver(new MavlinkObserver() { 
   @Override 
   public void onMavlinkMessageReceived(MavlinkMessageWrapper mavlinkMessageWrapper) { 
     //Log.d("Received Mavlinks:", mavlinkMessageWrapper.getMavLinkMessage().toString()); 
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MAV receive " + mavlinkMessageWrapper.getMavLinkMessage().toString(),Toast.L‌​ENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
})
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: After the drone is connected, I simply call this function upon pressing a button and it crashes. this.drone.addMavlinkObserver(new MavlinkObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onMavlinkMessageReceived(MavlinkMessageWrapper mavlinkMessageWrapper) {
                //Log.d("Received Mavlinks:", mavlinkMessageWrapper.getMavLinkMessage().toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MAV receive " + mavlinkMessageWrapper.getMavLinkMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for the crash? There's not much more to go on without that